# Multiple language issue in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiple-languages

[image][image]enter image description hereI am using 2 type edit text in my login page. In Arabic EditText gravity is END.But hint in EditText getting left align Why?.  When i give inputType="textPassword" no issues. Issues in  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

EditText code given below

```
<EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:hint="@string/userName"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
       android:gravity="end"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:gravity="end" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing :

```
android:gravity="end"
```

In the ***first `EditText`***. It should automatically make the text `RTL` if you already placed arabic `values-ar` in values folder.

---

Don't forget to add:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` also.

**Update;**

Didn’t get you at first but, add these:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"           
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

This will make the layout & text direction `rtl` and should help for the purpose.

Comment: Now hint is right aligned. But when i start type it getting left align

Comment: Adding `android:textAlignment="viewStart"` with `android:textDirection="locale"` should help then.

Comment: android:textAlignment="viewStart" now hint is left align.

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true" already added in manifest.  i think issues in android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

Comment: I have values-ar file. Hint is arabic. It is atomatically getting left align. But whehn i start typing it should start from left. So i try with android:gravity="end" or android:textAlignment="viewStart". Then hint getting problem

Comment: It's because of andorid and `android:textAlignment`. If layout or android direction is `RTL`, it starts from right to left if you write rtl words and if you write english in a RTL direction, it starts from left to right of course. That doesn't seems to be an issue tho.

Comment: Now its working fine when i add this two line in android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl" in my xml file

Comment: Glad to hear that. I actually didn’t get you at first but, glad to hear it’s working now. I’ve added the codes to the answer for future searches. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                style="@style/Widget.EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:layoutDirection="locale"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textDirection="locale" />
    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/Widget.EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:layoutDirection="locale"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textDirection="locale" />
```